# Jackson keeps throwing com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException even when using the example code. Is there anything wrong with my maven?

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson

im working on a little private project but its my first time using maven. To get started i just wanted to test parsing a JSON file using Jackson but all I am getting is a `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException` and  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`.

Since nothing worked for me I just tried copying the example code from  [Jacksons GitHub-Page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/). So right now my code looks like this:

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    public class MyValue {
        public String name;
        public int age;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MyValue value = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":13}", MyValue.class);
        }
    }
```

And my *pom.xml* like this:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.hslr</groupId>
        <artifactId>hslr</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <jackson.version>2.15.0-rc3</jackson.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
    </project>
```

But I keep getting the two Exceptions, so i was wondering if there was anything wrong with my code or maven setup? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you getting runtime exceptions (code runs, but fails), or are you getting compilation errors? Since you can't get 2 exceptions at the same time, I suspect it's compilation error, you need to either handle those exceptions, or you have to declare your method that it throws them.

Comment: Are you getting a _compilation_ error? Add `throws JsonProcessingException` to your `main` method, or otherwise handle that exception in a `try-catch` block. Are you using an IDE? It should warn you about this. See also the JavaDoc for [`ObjectMapper::readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: A try-catch block helped, apparently didn't read the error message correctly. Thank you both @Chaosfire and @andrewJames!